# Debug Javascript in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What is the best way to debug javascript code in Visual Studio 2013?
Is it possible having IDE support as c# code debugger? What about plugin like ReSharper?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find your answer in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) blog.

Hope its what you are looking for.